# Blurry screenshots and pdf outputs with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i am having issue with puppeeter pdf/webp/png exports

When I try to very basic example from the official doc

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Navigate the page to a URL
await page.goto("https://developer.chrome.com/");

// Set screen size
await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

const screenshot = await await page.screenshot({
  quality: 100,
  type: "webp",
});

res.set("Content-Type", "image/webp");
res.send(screenshot);
```

My image is always blurred
[image: blurry]

I tried a lot of thing, but couldn't figure out the reason. Do someone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem is in the line `await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });`. Those dimensions are pretty small for a modern screen and your image viewer scaling the image up can lead to blurriness. Try `{width: 1920, height: 1080}` for FullHD.

Comment: Thanks, again the screenshot is blury I think. Actually, my aim was to get png/pdf for given sizes (eg width: 480, height: 550).